# The inequality $\dfrac{1}{\ln^2\left(1+\dfrac{1}{x}\right)} \dfrac{1}{(x+1)x}-1>0$

Tags: calculus, inequality

How to prove, for every $x>0$
$$\dfrac{1}{\ln^2\left(1+\dfrac{1}{x}\right)} \dfrac{1}{(x+1)x}-1>0.$$

Comment: Does $ln^2()$ mean square of the logarithm or take the logarithm twice?

Comment: Which operator is between first and second fraction ?

Comment: @pedja  multiple

Comment: @Henry $(ln())^2$

Comment: Define $f(x)$ as : $$f(x)=\frac{1}{x(x+1)}-(\ln(x+1)-\ln x)^2$$ then calculate $f'(x)$ and try to show that $f'(x)>0$ for all $x>0$ .

Comment: Have you heard about: $$ 1-\frac{1}{x} < \log x < x-1$$?

Comment: @Peter I think I will reconsider the problem

Comment: Alternately use: $$ \frac{1}{x+1} \leq \log \left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right) \leq \frac{1}{x}$$

Comment: @gingerjin: the @-notification system doesn't work the way you think it does. [See this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work). In particular, you cannot summon any user who has not already commented on the thread.

Comment: @Peter It seems that I can't work out the problem with the use of the inequality above

Answer (score 1):

Here are some hints or ideas.

Exploring a few equivalent algebraic reformulations, for $x>0$,
$$
\dfrac{1}{\ln^2\left(1+\dfrac1{x}\right)}
\cdot \dfrac1{(x+1)x} - 1 > 0
$$
$$
\iff
\ln^2\left(1+\dfrac1{x}\right) <
\dfrac1{(x+1)x} =
\dfrac1{x}-\dfrac1{x+1}
$$
$$
\iff
\ln\left(1+\dfrac1{x}\right) <
\dfrac1{\sqrt{x(x+1)}}
$$
$$
\iff
\ln\left(1+u\right) <
\dfrac{u}{\sqrt{u+1}}
\quad
\text{for}
\quad
u=\frac1x>0.
$$
The last of these is fairly easy to work with. Setting
$$
f(u)=\ln\left(1+u\right),
\quad
g(u)=\dfrac{u}{\sqrt{u+1}}=(1+u)^\frac12-(1+u)^{-\frac12}
$$
we see that
$f(u),g(u)\geq 0$ for $u>0$,
that $f(0)=g(0)=0$,
that $f(u),g(u)\approx u$ for $u\approx0$,
and that
$$
\lim_{u\rightarrow\infty}\frac{f(u)}{g(u)}=0
$$
(using [L'Hôpital's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule) rule)
so graphing the two functions should get us almost there.
For this, we probably only need the first one or two derivatives,
$$
f'(u)=\left(1+u\right)^{-1},
\quad
g(u) = \frac{ (1+u)^{-\frac12} - (1+u)^{-\frac32} }{2}
     = \frac12u(1+u)^{-\frac32}
$$
which at zero are
$$
f'(0)=g'(0)=1
\quad\text{and}
$$
$$
f''(0)=-1,\quad g''(0)=-\frac12.
$$
This should be enough to produce a convincing graph
something like below,

[image]

made with [sage](http://www.sagemath.org/) ([online](http://www.sagenb.org)).

```
var('u')
G = plot(log(1+u),      (u,0,10),color='red')
G+= text('f(u)',           (3,1),color='red')
G+= plot(u*(1+u)^(-1/2),(u,0,10),color='blue')
G+= text('g(u)',           (1,1),color='blue')
G.show()
```

For the full Taylor series (which we probably don't want),
we would need the $n^\text{th}$ derivatives
$$
f^{(n)}(u)=\frac{(-1)^{n-1}(n-1)!}{(1+u)^{n}}
$$
and
$$
g^{(n)}(u)
=\frac12a_{n-1}(1+u)^{\frac12-n}-a_n(1+u)^{-\frac12-n}
$$
for $n>0$, where
$$
a_n
=(-1)^n
\left(\frac12\right)
\left(\frac32\right)
\cdots
\left(\frac{2n-1}2\right)
=(-1)^n
\frac{(2n)!}{2^{2n}n!}
=\left(n-\frac12\right)a_{n-1}
$$
so that
$$
g^{(n)}(u)
=a_{n-1}\frac{\frac12(1+u)-\left(n-\frac12\right)}{(1+u)^{n+\frac12}}
=a_{n-1}\frac{1+\frac{u}2-n}{(1+u)^{n+\frac12}},
$$
but there is probably an easier way than using the full Taylor series.

Answer (score 0):

Define the function:
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{ln^2(1+\frac{1}{x})}\frac{1}{x(1+x)}$$
The reciprocal of this function must be less than $1$.
Note that $$\lim_{x=\infty}{f(x)^{-1}}=1$$
and that $$\lim_{x=0}{f(x)^{-1}}=0$$
Because the derivative of the $f(x)^{-1}$ is never zero, this means that $1$ is an asymptote because there isn't a maximum between zero and $+\infty$